# Invalid frame dimension (negative or non-finite) when trying to define Capsule frame height in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, frame

I'm trying to define the height of a capsule in SwiftUI from a structure da that transforms `String` into `double` and does some calculation over it, just like the example bellow.

```
struct graphLenght{
       var energiaOne: String
       
       init(energiaOne: String){
           self.energiaOne = energiaOne
           
       }
       
       func energyOne() -> Double{
           let formatter = NumberFormatter()
           formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "pt_BR")
           formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
           let energyOne = formatter.number(from: energiaOne) ?? 00

           return Double(truncating: energyOne)
       } 

       func maxValue() -> Double{
           return max(energyOne(), energyTwo(), energyThree())
       }
       
       func maxValueGraph() -> Double{
           if maxValue() <= 0 {
               return 1
           }else{
           return round(maxValue() * 1.1)
           }
       }
       
       func lenghtConcrete() -> CGFloat{
           return CGFloat(((225 * energyOne())/maxValue()))
       }
```

although when I try to use  `graph.lenghtConcrete`  in  `.frame`   (just like bellow) the warning **invalid Frame dimension (negative or non-finite)** keeps showing.

```
Capsule()
    .frame(width: 14, height: abs(CGFloat(graph.lenghtConcrete())))
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
```

One observation the return of  `maxValueGraph()` is always **1**

How can I solve this issue??

Comment: Have you checked if `formatter.number(from: energiaOne)` is `nil`? Because then `energyOne()` will return `0` and I assume the others are similar, therefore `maxValue()` will be `0`. You will then be dividing by zero in `lengthConcrete()` which is not a number.

Comment: I have. When I tried to run the code in playground the values were correctly transformed from string to double by `func energiaOne()`